# How can I replace Nth delimiter in a csv file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv-simple

I have a comma seperated csv file as a sample like:

```
1,92345,92345,Dear user, this is your amount , 2016-10-10 
2,92345,92345,Dear user, this is your amount , 2016-10-09
```

I need to replace 4<sup>th</sup> comma `,` only after the `Dear user` with a pipeline `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can specifically tell `sed` which occurrences of pattern only you want to replace, so:

```
sed 's/,/|/4' infile
```

Or with different solution would be:

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]*,)([^,]*,)([^,]*,)([^,]*),(.*)/\1\2\3\4|\5/' infile
```